# How to format XPath for schedule task on event?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have written a script that i want to trigger any time a user is granted Domain Admin rights. I canno trigger this through event viewer as our Domain Controller is running on Server Core and the option to Attach Task to this Event is grayed out when you connect to Event Viewer remotely. Trying to use SCHTASKS I enter the following:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "Event Monitor" /TR $command /SC ONEVENT /RL Highest /RU $cred.Username /RP $password /EC ScriptEvents /MO *[System/EventID=4728]
```

The error I get is `The specified channel could not be found`. I can't figure out what I need to enter for the XPath for it to trigger properly. Could someone help out? Here is the contents of the Event:

```
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-54784994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}" /> 
  <EventID>4728</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>13826</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-24T12:11:54.847043800Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1050228</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="552" ThreadID="1580" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel>
```

Comment: think this question may be answered in https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking in the future, the problem was in both the formatting of the /MO switch and in the /EC switch. Here is how I solved it:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "Event Monitor" /TR $command /SC ONEVENT /RL Highest /RU $cred.Username /RP $password /EC Security /MO "*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and EventID=4728]]"
```